# google calendar update timezone issue

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

i am trying to update my existing event of google calender.

While update event i also want to update timezone too.

So while updating time zone i am getting this error.

```
string(517) "{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Value 'emailaddress@gmail.com' in content does not agree with value 'primary'. This can happen when a value set through a parameter is inconsistent with a value set in the request."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Value 'emailaddress@gmail.com' in content does not agree with value 'primary'. This can happen when a value set through a parameter is inconsistent with a value set in the request."
 }
}"
```

This code I am using for update timezone.

```
$event_id = 'event id';
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$event = $service->events->get('primary', $event_id);

/* Updating timezone (**This is causing issue**) */             
$calendar = $service->calendars->get('primary');
$calendar->setTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam');
$updatedCalendar = $service->calendars->update('primary', $calendar);

$event->setSummary($clientName); // Summery of calender 

$event->setDescription($treatmentname); // Description of calender

/* Update start time */
$startTime = '2018-11-01T08:00:00';  
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($startTime);
$event->setStart($start);

/* Update end time */
$endTime = '2018-11-01T09:00:00';
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime($endTime);
$event->setEnd($end);

/* set single event not recurring */
$event->setSingleEvent(true);

$updatedEvent = $service->events->update('primary', $event->getId(), $event);
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code is it failing which call?

Comment: $calendar->setTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'); at here.

Comment: I can see that you are trying to update the timezone of the calendar itself, are you trying to update from the calendar itself or just the event?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 while i am updating event the start time and end time needs timezone. so i add the code which i found in stackoverflow.